# I copy and paste image on EditText, but EditText show me 'obj'

Tags: android

Adding an image on `EditText` works fine.  However, copying an image is another problem.

When I insert an image on `EditText` by using `ImageSpan` it shows correctly, but I copy inserted image, EditText shows me only 'obj'.

Is there somebody who know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation for the `ClipboardManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html) currently you can only retrieve text from the clipboard so I don't think it will be possible for you to paste an image.

You can hook into the paste into the `EditText` using the [`onTextContextMenuItem()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextContextMenuItem(int)) so it may be possible to create the `ImageSpan` manually but I don't think there will be an image in the Clipboard to paste.

Answer (score 0):

I think android 2.4 will merge 3.0's ClipboardManager ability to copy any intent data.
http://gametest2.ruixinonline.com/docs/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html